# How to connect PHP with Windows WCF

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services, wcf, soap

is it possible to connect the wcf client with php ?
on one side there is a wcf with a very simple function

IService1.vb:

```
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Function AddNumber(ByVal number1 As Integer, ByVal number2 As Integer) As Integer

End Interface
```

Service1.vb:

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Function AddNumber(ByVal number1 As Integer, ByVal number2 As Integer) As Integer Implements IService1.AddNumber
        Return number1 + number2
    End Function

End Class
```

the url's are

```
svcutil.exe 

http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceTest/Service1/?wsdl
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceTest/Service1/?singleWsdl
```

and the php:

```
<?php

$soap = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceTest/Service1/?wsdl",
   array('soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_2',
         'location'=>'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceTest/Service1/'));


$result = $soap->__getfunctions();

if(is_soap_fault($result))
{
 print(" Fehlercode: $result->faultcode | Fehlerstring: 
         $result->faultstring");
}
else
{
 print_r ($result);
}

$retInt = $soap ->__call('AddNumber', array(2,2));
echo $retInt;
```

The `print_r($result)` shows me the actual wcf functions `Array ( [0] => AddNumberResponse AddNumber(AddNumber $parameters) )` 
But when i access the `AddNumber` function i get a FatalError

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a: DeserializationFailed] The formatter caused an exception when the message was deserialized: An error occurred while deserializing the body of the request message for the AddNumber operation. The ending element "Body" from Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was expected. Found "element" param1 "from Namespace" "". (20): SoapClient -> __ call ('AddNumber'). This is the default path for the current path. , Array) # 1 {main} thrown in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ SOAP \ index.php on line 20 (translated)